# I embeded youtube video in my bootstrap page and it's not visible in safari. How can I change it?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, youtube, safari

I followed this link http://getbootstrap.com/components/#responsive-embed and tried to embed youtube video on my webpage. I tried putting link to youtube with `http` and `https`, failed in both ways in Safari.
I basically use:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
    <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/v/myvideoid">
</iframe>
</div>
```

What is really weird for me is the fact that when I enter my page in chrome everything works, but when I open safari - there's no movie, but the page starts to download a text file with a name of myvideoid and the content is weird... this is a couple first characters from that file:

```
CWSN7x⁄Ì:˘w«y3ªÃ$H§Hë‘ )RKoYîMQºdä§I…í”ã∞¨µ¿¬ªR¥„∆
q‚ÿπ‹§á“¥I£ÙH”∫m‹¶È›¶M€ÙnHπ±_Í{yØ}˝˙ã˙Õ etc...
```

what's the issue here and how can I make it work (in safari and in ios too)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you got the link structure wrong?

> https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid

Try using:

```
<div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
  <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/videoid"></iframe>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have seen a similar issue previously, I recommend you try changing the source of the video from https:// to http:// as follows.

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="http://www.youtube.com/v/videoid">
```

This should fix your issue